# Value property on input field changes after a second user interaction - React

Tags: reactjs

I have a form with two input elements - one for name (type="text") and one for age (type="number"). I manage the form state in the parent component. I have my handler methods and everything set up. The form state changes when user types. Also the input value property on the name field receives its value based on the current state, but the number field does not receive it while user types but on a second interaction with the page (a click somewhere else let's say) 
Here is my Form component:

```
const Form = (props) => {
    return (
    <div className="col-md-4 form">
      <form id="myForm">
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Please, enter your name</label>
          <input onChange={props.inputChanged} id="name" type="text" className="form-control" name="name"
                 placeholder="Name" value={props.data.name}/>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>How old are you?</label>
          <input onChange={props.inputChanged} id="age" type="number" className="form-control" name="age"
                 placeholder="Age" value={props.data.age}/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the parent class based component which owns the state:

```
class DbControls extends Component {

  //INITIAL STATE
  state = {
    name: '',
    age: '',
    greeting: 'hello',
    role: 'admin'
  }

  //HANDLE USER INPUT FOR NAME AND AGE
  inputHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.target.id === 'name') {
      this.setState({name: e.target.value})
    } else if (e.target.id === 'age') {
      this.setState({age: e.target.value})
    }
  }

  //HANDE USER PREFERENCES FOR GREETING AND ROLE
  selectHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.target.id === 'greet') {
      this.setState({greeting: e.target.value})
    } else if (e.target.id === 'role') {
      this.setState({role: e.target.value})
    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          <Form data={this.state} inputChanged={this.inputHandler} selectChanged={this.selectHandler}/>
          <div className="col-md-6 table">
            <Table tableFor="Admins table"/>
            <Table tableFor="Moderators table"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am not sure if this is an actual problem but I was just curious what might be the reason for that behavior?

Comment: tried to run your code and had no issues

Comment: try to type in both name and age input fields and watch the element into the inspector while typing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per some of your comments i understand that the real issue you are facing is the the `DOM` value **attribute** is not in sync with the value **property**.

This is by design, there is a lot of talk about this issue and it mostly related to the confusion people do with:

1. `jsx` value attribute / property
2. DOM (devtools html) value attribute

These are not the same thing.

There is another thing to consider, related to passwords exploit.

You can read [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11896) for better understanding and more details.

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @IvoStoynovski was this answered your question?

Comment: Yes, sure. I was just about to provide a codepen code example, but your answer made this one clear :)

Comment: @Naple Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify how the inputs are setting state based upon the input's `e.target.name` and `e.target.value`. By design, the DOM number input value will only update when unfocused, but state is always up-to-date.

Here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/qzl5knl4kj

**formInputs.js**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

export default ({ age, handleChange, name }) => (
  <Fragment>
    <label>Please, enter your name: </label>
    <br />
    <input
      onChange={handleChange}
      type="text"
      className="uk-input"
      name="name"
      placeholder="Name"
      value={name}
      style={{ width: 300, marginBottom: 10 }}
    />
    <br />
    <label>How old are you?</label>
    <br />
    <input
      onChange={handleChange}
      type="number"
      className="uk-input"
      name="age"
      placeholder="Age"
      value={age}
      style={{ width: 300, marginBottom: 10 }}
    />
    <br />
  </Fragment>
);
```

**index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import FormInputs from "./formInputs";
import "uikit/dist/css/uikit.min.css";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    age: "",
    greeting: "hello",
    role: "admin"
  };

  handleChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => this.setState({ [name]: value });

  handleFormClear = () => this.setState({ age: "", name: "" });

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { age, name } = this.state;
    if (!age || !name) return;

    alert(`Name: ${name}, Age: ${age}`);
  };

  render = () => (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
      <h1>Mixed Input Fields</h1>
      <FormInputs {...this.state} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
      <button
        style={{ marginBottom: 20, marginRight: 10 }}
        type="submit"
        className="uk-button uk-button-primary"
      >
        Submit
      </button>
      <button
        style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
        type="button"
        className="uk-button uk-button-danger"
        onClick={this.handleFormClear}
        disabled={!this.state.name && !this.state.age}
      >
        Clear
      </button>
      <div>
        <pre style={{ margin: "auto", width: 300 }}>
          <code>
            Name: {this.state.name}
            <br />
            Age: {this.state.age}
          </code>
        </pre>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```